# WebGLRenderTarget image aliased

Tags: three.js

After sorting out the issues [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45331120/readrendertargetpixels-results-all-zeroes), I was finally getting image data from my render target. *BUT*, that image data does not seem to use anti-aliasing. (It also doesn't seem to have any alpha values where 0 < a < 255, but that may be a different issue).

I saw [in this thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/568) that anti-aliasing isn't available for render targets, but that was in 2011. Is that still the case? Do I need to employ post-process anti-aliasing if I want it for my render target?

This issue is present in both r76 (what I'm using from my previous question) and even the latest, r86.

Here's an example image, if it helps. The gray background is the image rendered to the main canvas, while the transparent background comes from the render target. You can really see the aliasing on the edges between the faces.

[image]

Comment: What three.js does for anti-aliasing is up to three.js. It could use various versions of anti-aliasing from post processing types to higher resolution or none at all.

Comment: @gman Agreed. The only info my searches turned up was old (in age, not relevance), and I would have kicked myself if an easy-mode switch had been added that made people stop talking about it. :)

Comment: i'm curious if you ever found a way to fix this?  I'm running into the same issue between geometry in the scene where it isn't hardware blended against the canvas background.  I'm also using render targets for texture antialiasing using post-process...

Comment: @Steve That's pretty much what I resigned to--applying AA in a post-process. Now I was using the render target to create off-screen renders, so I could afford to do super-sampling, and run it through a heavier-duty software AA than, say, FXAA. But that's unique to my use-case and may not help you at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this answer is some late (3 years later) but, in this discussion is the solution: https://discourse.threejs.org/t/why-is-a-custom-fbo-not-antialiased/1329.

- With the next release of three.js (R101), it’s possible to use a new type of render-target to solve this problem. WebGLMultisampleRenderTarget enables the support of multisampled renderbuffers. You can now perform “render-to-texture” and have an antialiasing render result. A post-process AA like FXAA is not necessary anymore.

Important: It’s required to use a WebGL 2 rendering context since multisampled renderbuffers is a WebGL 2 feature. -

Comment: This is great, thanks for the info. I'm marking this answer as correct (despite not fitting within the original environment) because it is the correct way to approach it moving forward.